# "They had lost all hope" vs. "They lost all hope"

Tags: past-vs-past-perfect

> The Napoleonic War had begun in 1816.  When it ended, they had lost
>   all hope.

OR

> The Napoleonic War had begun in 1816.  When it ended, they lost all
>   hope.

Which one of these sentences is correct?

Answer (score 1):

When it ended, they had lost all hope.

When it ended, they lost all hope.

Both the sentences are grammatical.

If you want to say that they lost all hope before the war ended, use the former sentence.

If you want to say that first the war ended and then they lost all hope, use the latter sentence.

I think the latter is better than the former here.

Comment: I agree with this until the last line.  Which one is better depends on the context (which is absent in the question).  The 1st example refers to hope being ground away until there was none left by the end of the war.  The 2nd example refers to holding onto hope right up until the war ended, at which point, hope became futile.

Answer (score 0):

Neither one.

> The Napoleonic War **began** in 1816. *By the time* it ended, they **had lost** all hope.

The date the war began is specific and in the past, so use simple tense.

"they lost all hope" indicates a changing outlook during the war (a period of time), so past perfect is OK.